# Equivalance of encryption and decryption in DES under bruteforce

Tags: encryption, des, brute-force-attack

I am studying the vulnerability of DES algorithm.

Let there be a DES system with 5 keys, 56bits each. Encryption works as follows: (It's in this order on purpose)

$C=DEC_{k1}(ENC_{k2}(ENC_{k3}(DEC_{k4}(DEC_{k5}(M)))))$

```
With k2=k3 and k4=k5

Where C = Cipher,
M = plain text
DEC = Decryption
ENC = Encryption
-kn = Is the number of key used, we have 5 keys so k1-k5.
```

So my question is, from what I understand, the difference between DES **encryption** and **decryption** is only the key used (or more like the order in which the keys are being used) so they just cancel out one another if the keys in two subsequent enc/dec operations are equal?

So, with bruteforce being applied, can C (the result) be figured in 2^(1x56) time complexity  vulnerability or in a 2^(3x56) one?
This is unclear to me, because if DEC and ENC are equivalent, then $DEC_{k4}(Dec_{k5}(M))$ will in fact cancel each other.
Same for $ENC_{k2}(ENC_{k3}(M))$.
Leaving us with $DEC_{k1}(M)$ which is, from what I understand, a single DES encryption on M. (Equal to $ENC_{k1}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because if DEC and ENC are equivalent, then $DEC_{k4}(DEC_{k5}(M))$ will in fact cancel each other.

Actually, just because DEC and ENC are similar (identical except for subkey generation) doesn't make them 'equivalent'.  $DEC_{k4}(DEC_{k4}(M))$ does not, in fact, cancel each other out (unless $k4$ happens to be a 'weak key', that is, one of four specific values).

On the other hand, to answer the larger question you're pondering, the cipher you're considering is essentially $F_{k1}(G_{k2}(H_{k4}(M)))$, for some key-dependent permutations $F, G, H$, and 56 bit $k_1, k_2, k_5$ values.  It should be obvious how a meet-in-the-middle attack would address this.

Comment: Thank you! So in conclusion, you are describing a O(2^3*56) efficiency case, for those F G H functions, except for that particular usage of weak keys, where 2 keys would cancel each other out and we would end up with O(2^1*56)?